# Constants using define() in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

I have several large files of constants using the PHP define() function that I had working well in Laravel 4, but now I am upgrading an app to Laravel 5 and I'm not sure how to best carry these files over.

The reason why I have more than one file for constants is because they are based on past, present, and future years (and they are large files with many constants).  Here's an example from one of the files of constants:

```
<?php

//Check to see if the user is logged in.
//  If no user, we can't know what catalog we should use
if (Auth::check()) {

    //The most recent catalog year will serve as the default for anyone
    //who signs up for a catalog year that is newer than the most recent
    //catalog year.
    if (Auth::user()->strg_4 == "2015 - 2016" ||
    intval(substr(Auth::user()->strg_4, 0, 4)) > date("Y")) {

        //Constants for Create course/Edit course pages
        define('MY_CONSTANT', 'This is an example of a constant');
    }
}
```

I've tried doing the following:  Adding the following block of code to my composer.json file:

```
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database",
      "app/Http/Controllers",
      "app/Models",
      "app/myclasses"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
      "app/constants2013andearlier.php",
      "app/constants20142015.php",
      "app/constants20152016.php"
    ]
  },
```

However, this didn't seem to work, probably since I have PHP conditional statements in my constants files.

I have also tried putting this into my base blade files for all of my views:

```
@include('constants.constants2013andearlier')
@include('constants.constants20142015')
@include('constants.constants20152016')
```

However, this didn't work either, as the files seem to not get read (I got errors saying "ErrorException in Course.php line 752:
Use of undefined constant MY_CONSTANT - assumed 'MY_CONSTANT'" where Course.php is one of my Models.

In my old Laravel 4 version of the project, I was defining these constants in the global.php file with the below code:

```
require app_path().'/constants2013andearlier.php';
require app_path().'/constants20142015.php';
require app_path().'/constants20152016.php';
```

Any suggestions?  Thank you.

Comment: What is a real example of a constant that you are defining? There is definitely a bit of code smell here

Comment: I gave one example of a constant, because I have quite a few constants that are similar and there's no point in repeating more of the same.  They all look like this:  
        define('MY_CONSTANT', 'This is an example of a constant');  Needless to say, there's nothing wrong within my constants files themselves, as they work perfectly in my old Laravel 4 version of this app.

Comment: I'm more interested on what kind of values you are storing in the constants. If it is simple text strings you may be better served using the Lang construct in laravel

Comment: There are only Strings, Integers and Decimals stored as constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd still be interested in hearing any other ideas or potential issues with the solution I discovered below:

1. I put my all of my constants files in a folder (named "constants") in the app directory.
2. From the command line, I ran: `php artisan make:middleware AddConstantsFilesToAllRoutes`
3. In the AddConstantsFilesToAllRoutes file, I added all of my constants files like this:

   require_once app_path('constants') . '/constants2013andearlier.php';
   require_once app_path('constants') . '/constants20142015.php';
   require_once app_path('constants') . '/constants20152016.php';
4. In Kernal.php, I added my new middleware file above to the `$protected middleware = []` array which adds it to all possible routes:

   \App\Http\Middleware\AddConstantsFilesToAllRoutes::class,
5. Be careful **NOT** to add the above code to the `protected $routeMiddleware = []` array or it will not add the constants files to all routes.
6. Of course, if you just wanted to add your constants files to selective routes, then that would be an excellent solution to do that; however, you would need to manually add those routes to the constructor of each controller where you want those routes to have access to those constants files.
7. Also, make sure that all of your controllers extend from the BaseController in order for the middleware to run on the routes for that controller.

Comment: You should port this to a service provider. You can include it in the boot method of the `AppServiceProvider` or do it in a new `ConstantServiceProvider`. It is a good idea to centralize includes within service providers.

Comment: Do you mind expanding on your answer a little bit?  If I just put the following code in the boot method of the AppServiceProvider I just get undefined constants again:  require_once '/constants/constants2013andearlier.php';
require_once '/constants/constants20142015.php';
require_once '/constants/constants20152016.php';

Comment: It should work, I have included some files with constants from the boot method of the `AppServiceProvider` and the constants display correctly.

Comment: Where did you store those files?  Would it matter that I have some conditional statements within my constants files?

Comment: Files were stored in `app/Library`, the conditional statements don't matter, but of course they should also have else statements, which doesn't exist in the snippet of your question.

Comment: I didn't put else statements in because each file covers a period of years that cover all possible years.  The constants file works when I put it in the locations I explained above, so I don't think missing else statments is a problem.  Do you mind sharing your code somehow?

Comment: All I have is `require app_path('Library') .'/constants1.php'` in the boot method of the `AppServiceProvider`.

Comment: And you are using Laravel 5.1?  Can you give me a snippet of code from within your constants1.php file?  Thank you for your help - it's appreciated.

Comment: Yes, Laravel 5.1.  `constants1.php` has an `if/else` for `Auth::check` and the `define` is identical to yours.

Comment: Thank you for your help - I got a simple example to work without using my condition statements, but when I add my conditions (that both make use of the Auth:: class), the constants become undefined again.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Further debugging reveals that when I take out the Auth::check condition, my year-based condition results in the error: "object not defined" error.  When I leave in the Auth::check condition, the error is that my constant is undefined.  I can verify I am logged into my app, and again these conditions work fine if I put this file elsewhere.  So my conclusion is that the AppServiceProvider is not picking up the Auth:: class.  Are you sure your "else" statement isn't always the one that is getting executed 100% of the time?

Comment: I'll check that, give me a few minutes.

Comment: You are correct, it always evaluates the else statement. I'll answer the way I did so it properly evaluates `if/else`.

Comment: @user2094178 I found a much better solution and edited it in to my original answer above!

Comment: I appreciate you letting me know this.